# Laravel integrity constraint violation when trying to use save

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm getting an error:

> Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: songs.slug (SQL: insert into "songs" ("title", "updated_at", "created_at") values (As Long As You Love Me test, 2014-10-22 04:09:02, 2014-10-22 04:09:02))

when trying to update a song. Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my update function:

```
public function update(Song $song, Request $request)
{
   $song->fill(['title' => $request->get('title')])->save();
   return redirect('songs');
}
```

Can anyone help me to  understand what is wrong here? I'm following along with a [Laracast](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch/episodes/9) to build this function and it seems like it should work its just giving me this constraint error. HELP PLEASE :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `protected $fillable = ['title'];` set in your Song model, since Laravel protects against mass assignment (using ->fill()), which means it will IGNORE any key/value you pass into the fill method that isn't previously defined in the $fillable property in your model!

Comment: Yes I did have that taken care of already. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

As this error says

```
Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: songs.slug (SQL: insert into "songs" ("title", "updated_at", "created_at") values (As Long As You Love Me test, 2014-10-22 04:09:02, 2014-10-22 04:09:02))
```

The `slug` column of your `songs` table is `NOT NULL` and you have not set a value to it before saving your model.

Comment: I understand that however what I don't understand is why the tutorial I am following shows no error when he did the same thing. https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch/episodes/9. Did the save-> change from being an update to an insert possibly across versions?